# Issue with method linked to System.Timers.Timer repeatedly sending email

Tags: asp.net

I have created an ASP.Net mail delivery application that is continuously sending emails. This behaviour persists even if the machine is restarted.

The code I am using is below:

```
          public void  SendScheduleMail()
          {
              System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                myTimer.Interval =20000;
                myTimer.AutoReset = true;
                myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
                myTimer.Enabled = true;                   
          }

          public void myTimer_Elapsed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
          {
              SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.xxx.com", 587);

              MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

              //password required////////////////////
              smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(tb_uname.Text, tb_pass.Text);
              message.From = new MailAddress("my email ID");
              message.To.Add(new MailAddress(tb_to.Text));

              message.CC.Add(tb_cc.Text);
              message.Bcc.Add(tb_bcc.Text);

              message.Subject = tb_sub.Text;
              message.Body = tb_body.Text;
              message.IsBodyHtml = false;


              smtp.EnableSsl = true;
              smtp.Send(message); 

          }
```

Comment: Who is calling SendScheduleMail? Also, you aren't holding your timer anywhere, so it should be gone by the time you leave the method - in fact, you are explicitly disposing it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @e-MEE---timer for scheduling mails

Comment: @RobertDondo--i never given condition for it(stop).

Comment: @dash= actually , i write dispose after running application and i want to send mail after some time intervals.but the mails are sending continuously.

Comment: Yes, but as you are disposing the timer and the scope of it is inside the method, I'm not sure how this code is sending multiple emails unless something else is repeatedly calling SendScheduleMail? At the moment, you create a timer, set it up, enable it, and then dispose it.

Answer (score 1):

You specify `myTimer.Enabled = true` to initiate the sending at intervals - you will need to specify `myTimer.Enabled = false` to stop the timer from ticking, and hence sending emails.

Strangely, though, you're disposing of the `Timer` potentially before the interval elapsed to raise the event.

Comment: now I stop the application but yet the mails are receiving by my mail system so what i do now?

Comment: Gosh, yes. I hadn't even noticed that timer disposal there... I wonder what that is doing... :) I was wondering about whether it may be GCed but concluded that the event attached would prevent that but the disposal is just wrong...

Comment: @Frank: in case you are unaware the dispose call would have just stopped the timer from doing anything. It does mean that it is hard to say for sure exactly why it is ever sending mail at all.

Comment: Removing the dispose will only mean it gets disposed when it gets garbage collected, which it will because the timer falls out of scope every time SendScheduleMail is called. You want a design that holds the timer at the class level, so you can have just one timer and start and stop that. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer for a good overview.

Answer (score 1):

the timer is set up to run `myTimer_Elapsed` every 20 seconds currently. This should be what it is doing.

Depending on the context of this the code should stop sending mails on rebooting if it is just an app but if it is installed as a service it may start again after reboot.

Also depending on the speed of your mailserver you may find yourself with a backlog of mail being processed that will continue to be delivered after the program has been shut down. It is important to differentiate between whether it is continuing to send or you are continuing to receive mails.

Lastly multiple calls to SendScheduleMail look like they will set up multiple timers so you may be in a state of having set up multiple ones of these calls...

Without knowing more about the intent it is hard to say any more on the program design but it may be that improvements can be made depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Are the mails still being sent or are they just continuing to be processed by the mail server? I discussed above some of the reasons and you'll have to give more information before I can tell you how to stop the mails. Is this code in an app or a service? Is this app currently running (ie does it run on startup, is it a service that starts on boot, etc.). It may be that there is no way to stop the mails being sent because they are already sent and being processed. In this case you'll have to try to get the mail server to destroy the messages if you have control of it. If not you just wait...

Comment: here i have used one mail delivery system for sending the mail,for which i have provided credentials.and it is not under my control so i cant stop it.I think you said right ;i need to wait.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not stopping is most likely it's because it has fired off a lot of events before you closed the app / restarted the machine.

I am not entirely sure why you use a timer but this is your problem, it will fire off repeatedly until you stop the timer which you never do.

Comment: I thought so initially, but the OP sets `AutoReset` to true, meaning it will only raise the event the first time.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: You have your meaning the wrong way round. Autoreset true means it will reset the timer and start again. false is the one that only runs once. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx if you want to double check)

Comment: @Chris I've just looked at the documentation and you are in fact correct.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the [Tread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) method?

Comment: The better question in my opinion would be why use `Thread.Sleep`? If you want to have something happen at a regular interval this is exactly what timers are for and depending on the nature of the program may cause you to need to worry about multithreading which the timer doesn't here (it does use multiple threads but you don't have to worry about them since they are not using anything that isn't local so threadsafe and such like is not a factor).